# Recurrent networks (RNN) and matrix definition of the input $x$ an weight matrix $W_{xh}$ for a time-series model?

Tags: time-series, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am playing with RNNs/LSTMs to do some time-series modelling. Now most of the tutorials on RNNs seem to focus on natural language processing tasks. Hence, most descriptions of RNNs begin with converting a sentence into a set of word vector, where each word is a one-hot encoded vector against a 10,000 or 30,000 word dictionary. Then as the model is trained, the weight vector is applied against these one-hot encoded word vectors to get the activation at that location in the sentence. So if I have a sentence with one-hot encoded vectors labeled as $x$, then the activation or hidden state $h_t$ is computed as.

$$
h_t = \tanh(W_{hh}\cdot h_{t-1} + W_{xh}\cdot x)
$$

Now for a time-series model, we don't encode the $x$ as a one-hot encoded vector. And this is where I am confused. **Instead of $x$ being a one-hot encoded vector, what is it encoded as?**

So I am just trying to understand mathematically what $x$ and what $W_{xh}$ looks like? Is $W_{xh}$ a discretized set of possible subsequent values or something? I am just not clear what that $x$ and $W_{xh}$ vector and matrix look like--what do the elements of those objects represent? Please let me know if anyone needs further clarification of what I am asking for.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

$x$ is the input to the layer, it's not encoded as anything if you don't encode it.

$W_{xh}$ is a matrix.
You can interpret it as a rotation matrix that takes $x$ to the space of $h_t$.

Comment: Ah okay, so this make a bit more sense. So the $x$ vector in a time-series would just be the sequence of time-series steps or lags, etc., [t-1, t-2, t-3, t-3, ...]. For $W_{xh}$ I was thinking that this notion of `state` referred to something meaningful like the transition probabilities between words or timesteps. But in reality, that interpretation is not true. More so, as I think you mean, the idea of "state" is just some arbitrary number of weights that are tuned. So it is not really an interpretable notion of "state," but more so an encoding artifact of some sort.

Comment: Somehow these weights in $W_{xh}$ are tuned to more accurately predict the outputs at each step in the RNN.